# Use http response headers for custom messages, after 200 OK successful operation

Tags: rest, http, http-headers

I'm coding a small restful server.
I can handle errors using an http appropriate response code, and i can place an error message in the response body. Assume some client is trying to access `http://very/reserved/area` without the required privileges:

```
Status: 401
Body: You are not allowed to perform this operation
```

I would like to add a message for 200 - OK responses aswell, for example assume some client post-ed some user's data to create a new account:

```
Status: 200
Body (JSON): {
    username: 'a fresh added user',
    email: 'his email address',
    name: 'his name'
    etc
}

__some_http_header__: 'A new user has been created.'
```

I know i could

```
Status: 200
    Body (JSON): {
        data: {
        username: 'a fresh added user',
        email: 'his email address',
        name: 'his name'
        etc
        },
        message: 'A new user has been created.'
    }
```

but this is exactly what i am trying to avoid.

In this way i can keep the response data lightweight, without meta-data overhead.

**Question**: is it a good practice? Which header would be suitable for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you can't create a header for this purpose.

X-Status-Message or something like that.

There's nothing wrong with the practice.

In this specific case, while the body can contain the resource just created as part of the 200 reply (nothing really wrong with that either), practice is to return a Location header with a link to the new resource, from which that representation can be retrieved.

Documenting the header falls upon your external documentation for the resource and its representations.